# MS-Access Earliest Time Issue

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT ID, AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS TransactionDate
FROM AppProsHist
WHERE [Description]='Non-Final Rejection'
GROUP BY ID, AppID, Description
ORDER BY Min([Transaction Date]) DESC
```

so lets say the AppID is "98" and the ID's are 12,14,16, (different numbers) and there are three dates which are described as "Non-final Rejection". The query is returning each date, in seemingly no order. I want just the earliest date for the AppID of "98".

Is this possible? I was under the impression the Min() would do this, however, it has not.

Comment: You included `ID` in the GROUP BY clause so you are getting the `Min([Transaction Date])` for each `ID`. If you want the overall `Min([Transaction Date])` for the `AppID` you need to remove `ID` from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Good Lord, That was all I had to do? lol Spent 2 days trying to fix nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included `ID` in the GROUP BY clause so you are getting the `Min([Transaction Date])` for each `ID`. If you want the overall `Min([Transaction Date])` for the `AppID` you need to remove `ID` from the GROUP BY clause.